# Command to find out version of cordova platform

Tags: cordova, npm

I know that I can set the version of a cordova platform thus *(for android)*:

```
$ cordova platform add android@<version>
```

But how can I tell what the current version is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just look at current platforms:

```
$ cordova plarforms
```

Platforms should be listed with installed versions.